# IE 10 + KnockoutJS = HierarchyRequestError?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I've simplified my problem as much as possible. It only happens in Internet Explorer (9 and 10 confirmed). I have a page rendered with this:

```
<html>
<body>

    <span data-bind="text:$data[0].Mileage"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.initChild = function (ko, viewModel) {
            window.ko = ko;
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.body);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My SPA calls

```
    var otherWindow = window.open('myurl', '_blank');
    var handler = function () {
        otherWindow.initChild(ko, report);
    };
    if (otherWindow.addEventListener) {
        otherWindow.addEventListener('load', handler, false);
    } else if (otherWindow.attachEvent) {
        otherWindow.attachEvent('onload', handler);
    }
```

I checked, the data arrives in the `initChild` method allright.

If I bind ANYTHING on the page, I get a `HierarchyRequestError` on the applyBindings call. My google-fu completely abandoned me on this, I'm completely clueless what's wrong.

Comment: It's taggged IE.  Does this not happen in other browsers?

Comment: no, it doesn't. The code (and it's original, more complex counterpart) works just fine in FF and Chrome.

Comment: `$data[0].Mileage` it seems pretty unlikely that your viewmodel is an array.

Comment: That's not a good idea. The `$root` and `$parent` context's will be confusing when do you that, and I am sure you will encounter other issues. Make a viewmodel object, and give it an array property.

Comment: @Tyrsius: that was true with the parent page's viewModel, here I was merely listing items in the child window. Thanks for pointing out the design flaw, I'll pay attention in the future. But of course in this situation, it is a nicety in a middle of an explosion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it was a symptom of this problem: [Using Javascript objects across separate windows in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975655/using-javascript-objects-across-separate-windows-in-ie)

basically, no matter HOW I passed the ko object to the child window, *something* got lost, and when I tried applying bindings, ko itself ran onto a DOM tracking error, and tried to insert something to somewhere it shouldn't have (possibly part of the parent DOM to the child DOM).

The solution was two-fold:

- Add the ko (and ko.mapping) scripts to the child window, to have it's own ko object
- serialize the model with ko.mapping to JSON, pass the string to the child window and deserialize it.

Horrible behavior, IE...

If anyone can come up with an actual explanation on WHY this was happening, I'll accept his answer instead.